# jQuery: handle click on submit button

Tags: jquery, input, submit

I try to handle a click on a submit button but it doesn't seem to work, as if my selector was wrong but I really can't tell what my mistake is.

Basically it's just the following:

```
$(".edit input").click(function() {
    $(".note").html($(this).val());
    $(".edit").html(editHTML);
});
```

Here is my test on jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/D7Teb/

Comment: A submit button submits a form, and when a form is submitted the browser redirects or reloads, so all javascript is lost as the browser has no concept of state.

Comment: Only if there is a form. Also, jQuery provides the preventDefault method which I think prevents the button from submitting the form. But yeah, if there is no form maybe I shouldn't use a submit button neither.

Comment: this may help http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `delegate` the events since you are adding some of the content after you run the initial listener code.  The below works with jQuery 1.7+ as it utilises the `on` method.  If you have to use an earlier version look inot the `delegate()` method.

http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/
http://api.jquery.com/on/
http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/D7Teb/1/

```
var noteHTML = $(".note").html();
var editHTML = $(".edit").html();
var noteAltHTML = '<input class="myInput" type="text" />';
var editAltHTML = '<button>Save</button>';

$(document).on('click', ".edit a", function () {
    $(".note").html(noteAltHTML);
    $(".edit").html(editAltHTML);
});

// Since you are adding the HTML after the initial running and adding of the listeners, you have to 'delegate' the event like this with 
$(document).on('click', ".edit button", function () {
    $(".note").html($(".myInput").val());
    $(".edit").html(editHTML);
});
```